# Can the title property of a directive on a aspx be referenced in the code behind to become conditional?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The directive on first line of my aspx page reads as below. The value of the title is "Print Root Cause Analysis". Is there a way of referencing the title property in the code behind so the resulting text can be conditional?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterBlank.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="rootcauseprint.aspx.vb" Inherits="contacts_rootcauseprint" title="Print Root Cause Analysis" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Page.Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to set the title dynamically:

```
Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Title = "Test 123"
End Sub
```

In order for this to work, you need to have a `<head>` element with `runat="server"` on your (master)page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
```